# Ask and answer question at Same Time

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, instant-self-answer

Is it possible to ask and answer to our question at same time ?

In reading this : https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

It's Ok.

But at the same time?

I ask this because : [Bootstrap 3: formatted checkboxes with Symfony & Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786954/bootstrap-3-formatted-checkboxes-with-symfony-twig)

The askers answer his question at the same time (same date, hour, minute).

Comment: When you ask a question you get to option to post an answer with it. So, yes, this is a **feature**.